# Why is there a process and behavioral error here? How do I fix this?

Tags: vhdl

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_misc.all;

entity alu is
  port (
    A, B : in unsigned(31 downto 0);
    sel  : in unsigned(2 downto 0);
    O    : out unsigned(63 downto 0));
end entity alu;

architecture Behavioral of alu is
begin
    process(sel)
    begin
        if sel = "000" then O <= (A+B);
        else if sel = "001" then  O <= (A*B);
        else if sel = "010" then  O <= shift_left(unsigned(B),1);
        else if sel = "011" then
            if (A <B) then O <= "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
            else O <= "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Those `else if`s should be `elsif`s.

Comment: The string length under the if condition assignment to O doesn't have a matching element between the target and expression.

Comment: Also a better way of assigning O the value of zero, instead of typing in 64 zeros, is to write                               O <= (others => '0');

Answer (score 2):

I can see two errors:

1. use elsif instead of else if otherwise you will need a lot of end if
2. the size of O does not always match the affected values